Expo React Native has not detected the SD card in my Devices
I have created the Expo App, but I am having an issue with the backup button. It needs to detect the SD card and save the backup onto it. When anyone clicks the button, the app should check if an SD card is available. If an SD card is available, the backup file should be created on it.
Here's the console.log
Checking path: /storage/sdcard1/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  Checking path: /storage/extSdCard/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  Checking path: /mnt/sdcard/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  Checking path: /mnt/extSdCard/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  Checking path: /storage/emulated/0/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  Checking path: /storage/0/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  Checking path: /storage/1/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  Checking path: /storage/self/primary/ {
  "exists": false,
  "isDirectory": false
}
 LOG  No SD Card detected.
 LOG  SD Card not found No external SD card was detected.

Here's the code
const getSDCardPath = async () => {
  const possiblePaths = [
    "/storage/sdcard1/",
    "/storage/extSdCard/",
    "/mnt/sdcard/",
    "/mnt/extSdCard/",
    "/storage/emulated/0/",
    "/storage/0/",
    "/storage/1/",
    "/storage/self/primary/",
  ];

  for (const path of possiblePaths) {
    try {
      const dirInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path);
      console.log(`Checking path: ${path}`, JSON.stringify(dirInfo, null, 2));

      if (dirInfo.exists && dirInfo.isDirectory) {
        console.log(`SD Card found at: ${path}`);
        return path;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error accessing path ${path}:`, error);
    }
  }

  console.log("No SD Card detected.");
  return null;
};

